# recursion for printing numbers

Tags: python, recursion

How print(n) will be executed?

```
def rec(n):
    if n>0:
        rec(n-1) #here it is used to call rec(9) again how 'print(n)'will execute
        print(n) 

rec(10)
```

Comment: as written you have an indentation error and an infinite recursion, so you're going to get an error message.

Comment: yeah i know but here in stackoverflow i can't indent

Comment: you can put in an editor and try

Comment: What are you unclear about? It will keep recursing down to `0`, then return back up printing n (`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`). When a function ends it returns to the calling stack.

Comment: #here it is used to call rec(9) again how 'print(n)'will execute????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are asking what does it output, then you can put it in an editor and see: https://repl.it/repls/IckyShinyProcedurallanguage

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

If you are asking how does `print(n)` ever execute, it's because of the stack. If you call a method and then do something after that method, the thing after that method will execute only after the method is finished running. In this case the program keeps calling rec(n) till n = 0, then that finishes so it goes and prints 1, then 2 etc

Comment: rec(n-1) ,it is calling again to rec(n) but below their is print(n) how does that print(n) executes

Comment: @sAGarm the print executes after the `rec(n-1)` executes. If this helped please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @sAGarm why did you remove?

Comment: i just tested whether it applies for both answers as am new here

Answer (score 0):

Every recursion code must contain:

- A base case (the case that tests if it should continue or not)
- A return statement (most of the time)
- The recursion by calling the function.

Usually, people use recursion to calculate things like the Fibonacci Sequence or factorials. Things that require multiple steps that take data from the previous step.

Your function is using recursion to run code again. It's viable, but recursion doesn't fit the purpose. You'd be better off with a loop, but if you're testing how recursion works, then this is a fine place to start.

Before `print(n)` is ever executed, the code will try to step down all the way through the recursion calls, until the base case stops it. Here, `n` will eventually reach 0, which will end this lowest step, and return to the previous step where `n` was 1.

The print statement here will execute first, being the lowest working step. As soon as `print(n)` finishes, the code returns to the next lowest step. This repeats until you finally return to the first step.

The output looks like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

If you're still confused, you can look at this longer explanation of recursion.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/